# Is it possible/sensible to customize Django's auto-through tables to include other fields...through-factory?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I know that django will helpfully generate a through table for simple many-to-many tables. However if you want to add information about the relationship, you need a 'linker' or through table. This example from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) gives an example:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I have in my design several tables/models like `group`, that vary mostly just by their [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) attribute. And I'll be adding more later.

Is it possible to customize what sort of through table is generated by Django's magic? If so is this sensible?

The sort of thing I'm talking about is this:

```
class CharacterSkillLink(models.Model):
    character =  models.ForeignKey('NWODCharacter', related_name='%(class)s_by_skill')
    skill = models.ForeignKey('Skill', choices = SKILL_CHOICES)
    value = models.IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=5)
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class CharacterAttributeLink(models.Model):
    character =  models.ForeignKey('NWODCharacter', related_name='%(class)s_by_skill')
    attribute = models.ForeignKey('Attribute', choices = ATTRIBUTE_CHOICES)
    value = model.IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=5

class CharacterArcanaLink(models.Model):
    character =  models.ForeignKey('Mage', related_name='%(class)s_by_skill')
    arcana = models.ForeignKey('Arcana', choices = ARCANA_CHOICES)
    value = model.IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=5
```

In the future there'll be more like these. It's be handy if there was some way to django, much like with the `through_field` attribute, which defines keys on the through table to use, that there should be extra values to add to it (e.g. `extra_field=value`).

Is this possible/sensible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, adding fields to a "through" table is a great pattern for many possible uses. I'm not sure that Django needs new syntax to handle this case, but if you think you're creating *lots* of these tables and mixing/matching different tables, perhaps some abstract mixins will simplify things. For Example:

```
class CharacterLink(models.Model):
    character =  models.ForeignKey('NWODCharacter')
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SkillLink(models.Model):
    skill = models.ForeignKey('Skill', choices = SKILL_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AttributeLink(models.Model):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey('Attribute', choices = ATTRIBUTE_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class CharacterSkillLink(CharacterLink, SkillLink):
    value = models.IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=5)
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class CharacterAttributeLink(CharacterLink, AttributeLink):
    value = model.IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=5)
```

Comment: That looks quite cool, but I now need even more classes in my `models.py`. Could I instead create a TraitMixin that has the shared properties of Skill, Attribute and Arcana (and others) and use  that instead?

Comment: You can do whatever you think is best. Also bear in mind that you can add methods to these mixins, so if you want all CharacterLink tables to have, say, a get_character_score() method, you can implement that in CharacterLink and all models that inherit from that will provide it. Planning ahead for methods and possible overriding may make the case for more fine-graned mixins... or it might not, in your case. Just one option to know about if you anticipate making a large number of tables with similar characteristics.